# Not able to search by certain columns when configuring mysql with lucene

Tags: mysql, lucene, solr

My database has three columns, which I configured lucene to index. However, I can search by only one of them. Complete description is the following:

I am following these instructions to configure solr to use mysql data:

http://digitalpbk.com/apachesolr/apache-solr-mysql-sample-data-config

I downloaded the jdbc driver, put it in /example/lib, and created a new `requestHandler` in /example/conf/solrconfig.xml.

My database table `items` has three columns:

1. `id`: int, primary, autoincrement key
2. `name`: varchar(256)
3. `description`: varchar(511)

So, I create following data-config.xml:

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
                    driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                    url="jdbc:mysql://SERVER/DATABASE"
                    user="USERNAME" 
                    password="PASSWORD"/>
        <document name="content">
            <entity name="node" query="select id, name, description from items">
                <field column="id"         name="id" />
                <field column="name"       name="name" />
                <field column="description" name="description" />
            </entity>
        </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Next, I edit schema.xml in /example/solr/conf to let it know about new names:

```
<field name="id"          type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"> 
<field name="name"        type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"> 
<field name="description" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true">
```

I had to uncomment the descriptions of `id` and `name` which were present in this file earlier, since they clashed with my descriptions.

Next, I imported the database (around 100K rows) successfully.

At the end of all this, I can successfully search by `name`, but I am unable to search by `description` or by `id`. I do not understand why this should be the case. Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Name field may be the default field name to search. So make sure you are referring the field names in your query like `description:queryString`.

Comment: You are spot on, hkn! I put `description:query` and solr searched in description. Now I need to figure out how to ask solr to search in all the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name field may be the default field name to search. So make sure you are referring the field names in your query.

To search in `description` field use query: `description:queryString`
To search in all fields use query: `id:queryString OR name:queryString OR description:queryString`

For more information please check http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ